Do we want questions about Staging Ground on Meta SE?
The Staging Ground semi-recently went live on Stack Overflow. The company has, in the past, mentioned that it may be extended to other sites on the network. At the present time, this has not yet happened.
We've recently gotten a couple of questions about the Staging Ground (bug reports specifically, one and two (now migrated), as well as a deleted support question). There's been a bit of confusion about whether or not they should be on-topic here. I'd like to try and draw a line somewhere, because I don't think the two bug reports I linked above are going to thrive very well here on Meta SE.
I would generally say that these questions should be posted on Meta Stack Overflow because the culture there would be better-suited to vote on, or provide support for, questions about it given that Stack Overflow is the only site on the network that currently has it turned on. There are naturally going to be more users to provide assistance with support questions and be able to reproduce bugs (and thus vote on them to indicate usefulness) than here on Meta SE where we harbor users from across the network that may not be frequent SO visitors.
Furthermore, Stack Overflow developers are frequently active over on Meta SO, about as much (if not more) than Meta SE. I'd say that discussions about how the Staging Ground could benefit the rest of the network (such as this announcement from the company, and other similar discussions) as well as bug reports that cause SG issues to bleed onto the rest of the network (such as Empty help section Staging Ground except Stack Overflow) would be on-topic and accepted. Furthermore, if the SG rolls out to other sites, we'd consider questions about it on-topic here since we're meant to harbor all questions that concern multiple sites on the network.
But enough about what I think. What do you think? Should questions about the Staging Ground, provided they don't have broader network implications, be off-topic here and migrated to (or encouraged to be reposted on) Meta SO?

I was considering asking this question myself, but looks like you got there first. Also, my thoughts on this, are, if Staging Ground gets added to other sites, and we had chosen to constrain them to MSO, what are we going to do? Will we have to mass-reopen questions here if they were closed?

@CPlus If the SG arrives to other sites, we'd have to start treating ourselves as an acceptable venue for SG questions, and we'd stop considering them off-topic. Ideally we wouldn't have any stragglers to reopen, as they'd be closed and roomba or be migrated away. If some stragglers remain, we could figure them out on a case-by-case basis. It's likely that, if there are stragglers, circumstances will have obviated them anyway.

Can questions be migrated from Meta.SE to other sites? Or will they have to be deleted and reposted manually?

@CPlus They can be migrated, just not by normal users.

I personally prefer these questions being asked on MSO but I think people asking SG questions on MSE is ok as well and these questions should stay there.

@Spevacus is there a reason we don't have a migration path from here to MSO and vice versa. A reasonable number of stuff do come each way.


Should questions about the Staging Ground, provided they don't have broader network implications, be off-topic here and migrated to (or encouraged to be reposted on) Meta SO?

In my opinion, yes, at least for now. Currently, as you said, Staging Ground is only active on Stack Overflow, and hence any question about Staging Ground, unless it is added to other sites, would fall under "Relates to only one specific network site".
However, if Staging Ground is added to other sites in the network then I think that some questions about Staging Ground that are applicable outside of the specific site would belong on MSE.

One issue would be that, by avoiding having the questions here, the 'final form' of the Staging Ground will be determined solely by the use case on Stack Overflow. This risks it not being well suited to the other sites. That may well be OK, as long as sites don't have to implement it.

@JonCuster "the 'final form' of the Staging Ground will be determined solely by the use case on Stack Overflow." Not sure I follow. Why would questions about the SO implementation of Staging Ground being on Meta.SO have any effect on other implementations of the Staging Ground? If the Staging ground is rolled out to other sites, questions about it can begin to be asked here (or on those specific sites).

@TylerH - it is far easier to influence design and function early on, rather than complaining about it after the fact. Once it 'works' on SO, whether it 'works' or not on other sites becomes irrelevant - it is what it is.

@JonCuster OK, it sounds like you're concerned about the design of the product, but this isn't asking about how to suggest design changes., it's asking where questions about the product (which is already designed and implemented) should go. Since it is currently a site-specific feature, questions about it should go on that site's Meta.
